# Android - How can I access the properties of a PDF page?

Tags: java, android, file, kotlin, pdf

I need to access the properties of a PDF page for my printer application.

These properties are;

1. Page size and width
2. Page margin (see the photo please)

[image]

How do I get these properties programmatically?

NOTE: I don't put any code sample because I only have a PDF file of type "File" right now.

Comment: The margin is not a PDF concept. It can't be queried from metadata or anything like that. The only solution if you really need to know this, is to look at the text (and or other elements) on the page, and figure out which of those comes the closest to the top of the page. Keep in mind that there may be page content *outside* of the page as well, you likely don't want to take that into account.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation (https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#kotlin),when you have the URI for a document, you gain access to its metadata. This snippet grabs the metadata for a document specified by the URI, and logs it

```
val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver

fun dumpImageMetaData(uri: Uri) {

    // The query, because it only applies to a single document, returns only
    // one row. There's no need to filter, sort, or select fields,
    // because we want all fields for one document.
    val cursor: Cursor? = contentResolver.query(
            uri, null, null, null, null, null)

    cursor?.use {
        // moveToFirst() returns false if the cursor has 0 rows. Very handy for
        // "if there's anything to look at, look at it" conditionals.
        if (it.moveToFirst()) {

            // Note it's called "Display Name". This is
            // provider-specific, and might not necessarily be the file name.
            val displayName: String =
                    it.getString(it.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME))
            Log.i(TAG, "Display Name: $displayName")

            val sizeIndex: Int = it.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.SIZE)
            // If the size is unknown, the value stored is null. But because an
            // int can't be null, the behavior is implementation-specific,
            // and unpredictable. So as
            // a rule, check if it's null before assigning to an int. This will
            // happen often: The storage API allows for remote files, whose
            // size might not be locally known.
            val size: String = if (!it.isNull(sizeIndex)) {
                // Technically the column stores an int, but cursor.getString()
                // will do the conversion automatically.
                it.getString(sizeIndex)
            } else {
                "Unknown"
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "Size: $size")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Provides information about the page size. But it doesn't give about top-margin. I need this to know where to start printing.